# -bash: dir: command not found - how to restore basic commands linux

Tags: linux, command, virtual-machine

This is inside a vm on the cloud, so I connected to the vm by ssh.

I was trying the add a path configuration in a vm and  I accidentally placed the path inside ~/.bash_profile just to be like:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin
```

instead of adding the path like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH
```

and now basic commands like dir,cat,vim,sudo, etc.. are not working on the vm, I would like to know how to restore them 
[image]

Comment: try pressing `ctrl+alt+f2` and log in as root. then edit your bashrc.

Comment: it get's printed the letter "Q", nothing else

Comment: the picture that you included, is that the terminal or the tty? if it's the terminal, do the steps above again, but do it outside of the terminal. mine shows up a tty anywhere i do it. for more info go to [https://www.ostechnix.com/how-to-switch-between-ttys-without-using-function-keys-in-linux/]

Comment: @AimanDaniel I conected to the vm by ssh

Comment: Try logging in as root via ssh and repeat the steps above. If it still doesn't work, contact the cloud provider.

Answer (score 0):

Enter with root account, and type `chsh [username]`. Enter. and then add /bin/bash. May be this is helpful.
*chsh -l    .This command will show types of shell u can change.